# navigation is giving me blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used ReactJS a year ago only once just for a small project, however, now I have a problem setting the navigation. The navigation on the old project it's working, I found out there is a new version of react-router-dom, I tried to implement the changes into the code but still, it doesn't work. I don't have a clue why :( any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

Console error:

```
Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.

The above error occurred in the <Route> component:
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {Nav} from './Nav';
import { Posts } from './Posts';

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav/>
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App/>}/>
            <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts/>}/>
          </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Nav:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from '../images/Logo.png';

export function Nav(){
    return(
        <div id="nav">
            <img src={Logo} class="nav-logo" alt="logo"/>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/Posts">Posts</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

index:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './components/App';
import {BrowserRouter, BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Router>
        <Route path='/' element={<App/>}/>
      </Router>
  </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Router updated quite a lot, I recommended read the documentation and
don't do anything in the `index.js` file usually to routing in `App.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
, document.getElementById("root"));
```

`App.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Nav} from './Nav';
import { Posts } from './Posts';

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App"> 
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Nav/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/posts" />} />
          </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```